The logic subtlety behind solving differential equations.
Let me first explain what has led me to ask this question.
When solving functional equations, it is often the case that through a link of implications (that is, uni-directional implications), we get several possible solutions for the functional equation. Then, we have to plug these functions into the original equation to see whether each of them really is a solution, as in the middle of our solution, some implications might be irreversible.
But this doesn't seem to be the case when solving differential equations. At least in most of the solutions I've seen, after the series of implications that leads to a possible solution, the author usually concludes straight away that the solution to the original differential equation is the derived expression, without plugging the whole thing back to double-check.
So I wonder why that is the case.
To illustrate this with an example, a solution that solves the differential equation
$$ x \frac{dy}{dx} - y = x ^ 2 \sinh ^ {-1}x\tag{E1}$$
would appear as follows:

Dividing through by $x$ on both sides and we get
$$\frac{dy}{dx} - \frac{y}{x} = x \sinh ^ {-1}x.$$
The integrating factor is $e ^ {\int -\frac{1}{x}\,dx} = \frac{1}{x}$.
Multiplying both sides by the integrating factor gives us
$$\frac{1}{x}\frac{dy}{dx} - \frac{y}{x ^ 2} = \sinh ^ {-1}x.$$
Which is:
$$\frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{1}{x} y\right) = \sinh ^ {-1}x.$$
Integrating both sides then gives
\begin{align*}
\frac{y}{x} &= \int \sinh ^ {-1}x \, dx \\
&= x\sinh ^ {-1}x - \int \frac{x}{(1 + x ^ 2) ^ {1/2}} \, dx \\
&= x\sinh ^ {-1}x - (1 + x ^ 2) ^ {1/2} + C.
\end{align*}
So the solution to the differential equation is
$$y=x ^ 2 \sinh ^ {-1}x - x(1 + x ^ 2) ^ {1/2} + Cx\tag{S1}$$
where $C$ is an arbitrary constant.

But this just doesn't sound right to me.
For instance, in the first step when dividing both sides by $x$, why don't we need to consider the case when $x = 0$, as we normally do when solving more basic equations such as $x ^ 2 = x$ ?
Also, why it is the case that this stream of implications, which essentially says that:

if
$$x \frac{dy}{dx} - y = x ^ 2 \sinh ^ {-1}x\tag{E2}$$
then
$$y=x ^ 2 \sinh ^ {-1}x - x(1 + x ^ 2) ^ {1/2} + Cx\tag{S2}$$

needs no longer backward verification by plugging the derived equation back into the original differential equation? It is quite clear to me that not every step we took along the way is irreversible (the first step, in particular).
Has it been because the sources of the solutions I've read about aren't that formal? Or is it because there is some underlying intricacy about differential equations which I'm yet unaware of?
Any informative response would be highly appreciated.

$x = 0$ is a singular point and some technical details have to be considered.

Okay. This is actually something that perplexes me. Hope someone could give some insights into the issue.

You’re correct in being uneasy. The way things proceed tends to be construction followed by validation. The constructive part begins with something like If $u$ satisfies this ODE, then, etc., with sometimes rigorous, sometimes formal, manipulation. In the end you still need to show it satisfies the problem at hand. Now if you solve a second order ODE without boundary or initial conditions and end up by whatever magic with something satisfying the ODE and with two degrees of freedom, you know you’re done.

Yes, that has bugged me as well. I find it helpful to keep in mind that the variables in question $x$ are in fact actual variables, that is they are thought of as entities that vary (in time or space or what have you). The basic logic of solving ordinary differential equations is then that to derive certain conditonal equations from a starting equation, where the conditions are imposed on the domain of the variables, the slogan being: “If I start with something that looks like this here, I also end up with something that looks like this there.” and “there” could be “wherever $x ≠ 0$”.

More specifically, the statements are of the form “Anything that behaves like this here, looks like this there”. You would then indeed need to verify that the converse holds, so “Anything that looks like there, behaves likes this here”. And then you would also need to consider what happens here that isn’t there, so for instance what happens at times/places where $x = 0$. What you will find, though, is that any solution you find most often smoothly extends to any region of the domain that has been excluded by such conditions as $x ≠ 0$ and hence still satifies the original equation.

It's a law that introductory courses in statistics and differential equations be taught hand-wavily. In any case—and this doesn't answer your main question—we can verify, for this entire group of ODEs, that the solution obtained this way is indeed correct.

@k.stm Yes, I also think it is logical that the converse should be verified. I guess you're right in saying that it is often the case the converse holds, and that's probably why most solutions don't explicitly verify the derived expression.

@ryang Interesting, I haven't heard of this hand-waving theory before.

@The_Eureka No no, all I'm saying is that for these particular examples, it is straightforward to verify (click on the link) that the hand-wavy method gives no extraneous solutions. Like I said, this observation (notwithstanding my flippant remark) doesn't generally address your query. P.S. Did you notice the typo in your post? Viz. particular integral versus integrating factor.

Oh, alright, sorry I've misunderstood you. Thanks for pointing out the mistakes in the post though.

Hello @ryang, it seems to me that your comment is a good (partial) answer. You should definitely write it for future readers, even if this will not necessarily be the answer accepted by the op :) (I mean, just link your previous answer on the other post in an answer)

An introductory text that is very careful with correct and precise statements and justifications, but which isn't an upper-level ODE theory text, is Differential Equations by Ralph Palmer Agnew (1960, 2nd edition). This book is also very well written in the readability/expository sense and it is even quite humorous in places.

Thanks for the recommendation! I'll check it out.

For first order linear equation you don't really need to be too concerned. Once we verify that the general formula obtained from multiplying factor is indeed a solution, we don't need to do that again for every concrete problem. Dividing by $x$ is indeed a slight issue. The general theory only tells you the formula works on $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,\infty)$ separately, but once you observe from the formula that it's defined and continuously differentiable everywhere, you know it actually satisfies the equation everywhere.

Okay, I get it. Thanks.
